# In TypeScript, how can I specify the types of the values in my object?

Tags: typescript

For example, suppose I have:

```
export function trade(positions: object) {
  ...
}
```

but instead of just specifying that 'positions' is an object, I want to specify that it is an object with values that must be Strings.

What is the syntax for that?

Edit:

To tighten the example, suppose I just want keys and values to all be Strings. Is there a syntax for that?

Comment: What do you mean by "with values that must be strings"? Do you mean that it can have any property, of any name, as long as the value of the properties are of type string? Why would you want that?

Comment: At best declare the full object. For your use case declaring an interface with an index signature might sufficem

Comment: `{[key: string]: string;}`. But again, you're not saying why you want that. In most cases, using classes and/or interfaces, with named and typed properties, is the correct way to go.

Comment: Honestly, it sounds to me like you should read the basic TypeScript handbook. This question is very basic. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share the object is as wide as "has string keys, and string values" you can use an index type:

```
export function trade(positions: {[key: string]: string;}) {
    // ...
}
```

If you want to make it more specific, it may be time to create an interface - even if everything is optional - as it will give you more design-time help when creating a positions object.

```
interface Positions {
    x?: string;
    y?: string;
    z?: string;
    t?: string;
}
```

This doesn't force any of the items to be present, but you'll get good auto-completion. If the members are required, you can make them non-optional.